# WP_Query strange behaviour with order ASC

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

I'm have a Responsive Child Theme and I'm writing a plugin that lists posts using responsive grid.

If I set order to DESC (in WP_Query) everything works ok, but with ASC I'm experiencing a very strange behaviour. Post get listed ok with ascending order but my function that gets post thumbnail no longer works. And it works with DESC... How can a wp query have an effect on my function?!?!?!

These are the shortcodes that work:

```
[myplugin category="0" order="DESC" orderby="date" limit="4"]
[myplugin category="0" orderby="date" limit="4"]
```

and this one does not:

```
[myplugin category="0" order="ASC" orderby="date" post_not_in="233" limit="4"]
```

This is the function I use to get the first image in a post:

```
function my_get_first_image( $postID ) {
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'post_parent' => $postID,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
    );
    $attachments = get_children( $args );
    if ( $attachments ) {
       foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        $fullImg = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
        $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'big' )  ? wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'big' ) : $fullImg;
         return '<a rel="shadowbox" href="'.$fullImg.'"><img class="nw_front_thumb" src="' . wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment->ID ) . '" class="current"></a>';
       }
    }
    return '';
}
```

Loop is a little longer so I paste it on paste bin. As you might figured out this code is in my plugin:

http://pastebin.com/cYrag67Y

edit:
http://pastebin.com/rw6NWEeV

Comment: please post the loop, it seems like you have an odd quirk

Comment: right now I don't have the access to the files... will post this evening or worst case tomorrow.

Comment: here it is... I hope this makes sense..

Comment: could you add the shortcode to here as well it seems like your are using it above but didnt paste that code?

Comment: you mean this... (see my edit)

Comment: where does your `while` loop end? theres no closing of it

Comment: probably accidentally deleted... well, this is not the issue...

Comment: your shortcode is missing the certain things would you like me to fix it for you... i dont know if you know they are missing...

Comment: not sure what your talking about.. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27358/discussion-between-user568021-and-david-chase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to use:

```
 the_post_thumbnail()
```

instead of wp_get_attachment_url()

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

I used to experience some issues with problems like that. Works perfectly with the_post_thumbnail().

A working example:

```
$myimage_html = '';
$large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
$myimage_html .= '<a rel="shadowbox" href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="'.the_title_attribute('echo=0').'" >';
$myimage_html .=  '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($id)).'">';
$myimage_html .= '</a>';
```